# When there are compiler errors and the last successful build is run, is all new code ignored?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, compilation, msbuild

In trying to get a VB ASP.NET project to run, I get, "*There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?*"

I was told to ignore the compile errors (of which there are dozens) and select "Yes" to run the last successful build.

But in this case, do any changes added get ignored? I would assume yes, if it is truly running the last successful build, which would theoretically ignore any changed/added code.

I cannot determine the answer to this empirically at this time (by, for example, adding some GUI change or such) because I get a runtime error ("*Could not load file or assembly 'ADODB' or one of its dependencies*") tersely described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038838/how-can-i-solve-the-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-adodb-or-one-of-its-depen).

Comment: I would say yes, newer changes are ignored (but I don't know for sure). If your project doesn't compile no updated .exe/output file(s) will be written/copied to the `Bin\Debug` or `Bin\Release` folder. I guess VS runs the old .exe/output that already is in there instead of updating it with working changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, code written after the last successful build is ignored.